# how to achieve Parallel execution in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

In my test suite we have 100 test cases in one file only

Eg. test_case_1
test_case_2
test_case_3
test_case_4
test_case_5

I want to execute this test case parallel(like test_case_1 and test_case_2 run at a time)
I have tried pybot robot framework but this executing test case from different file
note - i have only one file

Answer (score 1):

Robot does not have the ability to run test cases in parallel. You'll have to use an external tool such as pabot, or write your own code to split the tests into parallel test runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins as an external tool to configure your .robot scripts to run in parallel with the Jenkins pipeline. This is free to use. This will significantly reduce your execution time, it works well. Details at - https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/
You have to configure Jenkins job as Freestyle project and then add a step to run a windows batch command to trigger your robot script.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `pabot` to execute test cases in parallel within one suite. You need to use `--testlevelsplit` option.

For example `pabot --testlevelsplit [path to suite with 100 test cases]`.